# Confirrmation before deleting with jquery

Tags: jquery

I am able to delete the record using below code. Now i want to add conformation before deleting. How can i achieve that. I am quiet bad with jquery. Thank in advance.

```
    <script>
    $(function() {
      $(".del").on("click", function() {
        var $ele = $(this).parent().parent();
        $.ajax({
          url: "delete.php",
          method: "POST",
          data: { "member": $(this).data("id") },
          dataType: "html"
        }).done(function(msg) {
          $ele.fadeOut().remove();
        }).fail(function(msg) {
          alert( "Can't delete Member");
        }); 
      });
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a confirm dialog for this. Keep in mind that you can't style this, if you want a nicer solution you have to code it all yourself. The overlay, the logic for showing and hiding it, the return parameters for if the user confirms / denies.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".del").on("click", function() {
    if (confirm('do you want to delete this item?')) {
      // if the user hits "ok" then we go ahead and delete it
      var $ele = $(this).parent().parent();
      $.ajax({
        url: "delete.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: {
          "member": $(this).data("id")
        },
        dataType: "html"
      }).done(function(msg) {
        $ele.fadeOut().remove();
      }).fail(function(msg) {
        alert("Can't delete Member");
      });

    } else {
      console.log('no deletion happening!')
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button type="button" class="del"> Delete me </button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use *confirm* popup and depending on response you can cancel delete .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(function() {
  $(".del").on("click", function() {
    //if ok click
    if (confirm("Are you sure ? ")) {
      console.log(" confirm")
      var $ele = $(this).parent().parent();
      //ajax codes..
    } else {
      console.log("not confirm")
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="del" type="button">Click </button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can do it with confirm alert.

```js
$(function() {
      $(".del").on("click", function() {
        //if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete?')) {
           var $ele = $(this).parent().parent();
            $.ajax({
                 url: "delete.php",
                 method: "POST",
                 data: { "member": $(this).data("id") },
                 dataType: "html"
              }).done(function(msg) {
                 $ele.fadeOut().remove();
              }).fail(function(msg) {
                  alert( "Can't delete Member");
           }); 
         //} 
        
      });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
body {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
* {box-sizing: border-box;}

/* Set a style for all buttons */
button {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0.9;
}

button:hover {
  opacity:1;
}

/* Float cancel and delete buttons and add an equal width */
.cancelbtn, .deletebtn {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}

/* Add a color to the cancel button */
.cancelbtn {
  background-color: #ccc;
  color: black;
}

/* Add a color to the delete button */
.deletebtn {
  background-color: #f44336;
}

/* Add padding and center-align text to the container */
.container {
  padding: 16px;
  text-align: center;
}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: #474e5d;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

/* Modal Content/Box */
.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: 5% auto 15% auto; /* 5% from the top, 15% from the bottom and centered */
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%; /* Could be more or less, depending on screen size */
}

/* Style the horizontal ruler */
hr {
  border: 1px solid #f1f1f1;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}
 
/* The Modal Close Button (x) */
.close {
  position: absolute;
  right: 35px;
  top: 15px;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #f44336;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* Clear floats */
.clearfix::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

/* Change styles for cancel button and delete button on extra small screens */
@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .cancelbtn, .deletebtn {
     width: 100%;
  }
}
</style>
<body>

<h2>Delete Modal</h2>

<button onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'">Delete</button>

<div id="id01" class="modal">
  <span onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Close Modal">×</span>
  <form class="modal-content" action="/action_page.php">
    <div class="container">
      <h1>Delete Confirmation</h1>
      <p>Are you sure you want to delete?</p>
    
      <div class="clearfix">
        <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="cancelbtn">Cancel</button>
        <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="deletebtn del">Delete</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>

<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('id01');

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```